# c#: Strange pattern appears using bool = !bool

Tags: c#, boolean

I was making a mesh generator for a voxel chunk when I discovered a strange artefact when I was testing

I set the blocks to a bool which I flipped every time. this worked however a pattern appeared which I was not expecting

[image: the pattern]

the code generating the map is just a generic loop

```cs
for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
{
    for (int z = 0; z < breadth; z++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
            blocks[x * y * z] = i;
            i = !i;
            // if (i) { i = false; } this has the same effect
            // else { i = true; }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm just wondering what is causing this?

Comment: `blocks[x * y * z] = i;` - I suspect that doesn't do what you expect it to. (Hint: you'll be setting `blocks[0]` many, many times...)

Comment: damn, your right I meant to do ```blocks[ (x*width) + (y*height) + (z*breadth) ]```

Comment: I suspect you don't even mean quite that... be really careful with your indexes.